react native problem could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
info Opening app on Android...
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
13 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 10 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor     


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
   > java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


BUILD FAILED in 12s
BUILD FAILED in 12s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I add local.properties file & also downgrade my version of gardle but still unable to build my project in react native.


Try clean and sync project from android studio
Then un-install old app
Then re build from android studio so you can get where is error and if not an error then it's work.

Hope it's working.
